# changing version of node-sass to allow grunt build to finish normally

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm-install, node-sass

I recently took on managing a drupal 8 website while our organization searches for a permanent web developer (i.e. this is not a task I normally do).  I am currently trying to make some styling changes to the site, necessitating that I rebuild our drupal theme using grunt, npm, etc.
Originally I had trouble getting `npm install` to succeed, but found that switching to an older version of node/npm (v8.17.0) helped.  However, this raised a new problem. When I issue `grunt build` I see this error:

```
> grunt build
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: OS X 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (57)
>> For more information on which environments are supported please see:
>> https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v3.13.1
Warning: Task "build" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

For the record, re-running with `--force` doesn't help; the process terminates but without the build.

I noticed that a newer version of node-sass seems to support the version of node that I'm running on my OS (Mac OS 11.5): https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.14.1.  But my problem (I think) is that I'm not sure how to specify that I want to use this version.

The theme's `package.json` looks like so:

```json
{
  "name": "[obscured]",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~2.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify-es": "github:gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify#harmony",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~1.0.0",
    "grunt-sass": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-sass-globbing": "^1.3.0",
    "md5": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.8.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "find node_modules/ -name '*.info' -type f -delete"
  }
}
```

I'm not familiar enough with this stuff to know why `node-sass` v3.13.1 is getting used here. To my eyes it looks like `package.json` is requiring a version >= 1.0.0, but here my lack of familiarity is surely holding me back; there must be more going on.

If anyone could help me either force upgrading to `node-sass` v.4.14.1 or suggest another way to resolve the runtime error I'm seeing with `grunt build` I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as it happens, I was able to answer my own question.  Here's what worked for me...

Following [these directions](https://www.gavsblog.com/blog/node-sass-does-not-yet-support-your-current-environment) I un-installed `node-sass v3.13.1` with `npm uninstall node-sass`.  I then installed `node-sass v.4.14.1` via `npm install node-sass@4.12`.

This allowed me to re-install and then build the drupal theme.  There were some warnings, but I *think* things finished normally.

Woof.  This was really a bear.  In the end, it was a simple fix.  The issue for me has been trying to understand how all these bits of software fit, and where they store/retrieve data.  Seems like an incredibly complicated way to handle some not-very-complicated tasks.  But I know I'm just a tourist here; I'm sure there are good reasons for introducing this complexity.